# Compiling error when using struct within an inner class

Tags: c++

I could not find any answer that helped me understand why the following code does not compile.
Im declaring a struct within the private part of a class (Foo), and trying to use it from within an inner class (Bar) like this.

```
class Foo {
public:
    Foo();
    class Bar;

    class Bar {
    public:
        Bar();
        Foo::Node createNode();
    };

private:
     struct Node{
        Node(int d) : data(d) {};
        int data;
     };
};
```

And the compiler throws the following error:

`.../Foo.h:9:14: error: no type named 'Node' in 'Foo'`

Comment: A C(++) compiler reads from the top to the bottom, if at a certain line a type is not defined (because it is defined afterwards) it cannot be referenced. Solution: move the definition of struct node above the definition of class bar. BTW: if you have this struct private you will receive another error regarding visibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare the inner class before referencing it:

```
class Foo {
    class Node;
public:

    // ...
```